# Inflated xml Layout with a TextView has an onClick attribute, but it does not get called.

Tags: java, android, textview, layout-inflater

I have an XML layout file that has a TextView within a CoordinatorLayout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".SpecificProgramSelectionActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/saved_program"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/program_selection_border"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="addToSavedPrograms"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
```

And this code that inflates the layout and adds it into a Linear Layout in the activity's view.

```
for (PlayerWithObjectives player : players){
        name = player.getName();
        for (String objective : player.getObjectives()){
            objectives.add(objective);
        }
        nameView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_player_name_view, null);
        ((TextView)nameView.findViewById(R.id.saved_program)).setText(name);
        ((TextView)nameView.findViewById(R.id.saved_program)).setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        ((TextView)nameView.findViewById(R.id.saved_program)).setTextSize(20);
        linearLayout.addView(nameView);

    }
```

(This is the activity's layout XML)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SpecificProgramSelectionActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/specific_program_selection_linear_layout">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Everything looks fine in the app when I run it. Every inflated view shows up, the only issue is that the method that I specified in the onClick attribute for the inflated TextView does not get called. Why is that? Here is the method that is supposed to be called

```
public void addToSavedPrograms(View view){
    String name = (String) (((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.saved_program)).getText());
    namesToSend.add(name);
    editor.putStringSet("Tracked Players", namesToSend);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name + " was saved to preferences.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Why doesn't the method get called? I already saw all the other threads about using setContent() and stuff but that didn't work and it was not explained that great in the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the `onClick` code look like?

Comment: try setting click listener programmatically on inflated TextView.

Comment: @LAD I put it in the first block of xml in my post. And then the method, addToSavedPrograms I put in the last block of code.

Comment: @AamirKhan I tried that too but it did not work. It could be because I am inflating them and setting the onclick listener within a for loop because I have multiple I want to add? I'm not sure. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I just implemented your code and it is running.

Comment: The problem must be related to another part of your code, because the `addToSavedPrograms` method should be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.saved_program);
textview.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.saved_program:
       //call your function here
    default:
        break;

}
}
```

you can do it like this.

Comment: It did not work. From my understanding of similar threads, it has something to do with setContentView() and updating it to adjust for the new views that I inflated, but their suggestions did not work or I did not implement them correctly, either way, they were not explained well.

Comment: the above code is simply an implementation of onclicklistner. I am not an expert of android coding, but in my little bit coding knowledge if the method is not called that means on clicklistner may not implement properly..so I write a simple onclicklistner implementation...if it is not work then may be the method is called but it does not get any text in textView...do you check that??... and sorry for my horrible english

Answer (score 0):

Update:
First off, thank you to everybody that commented, your help was greatly appreciated. Your no judgment assistance is an awesome and welcome change from a lot of what I have experienced and seen on in this community.

Secondly, I figured out my issue. Or got my code to work at least. Once I got a better understanding of inflating layouts I changed this line of code

```
nameView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_player_name_view, null);
```

To

```
nameView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_add_player_name_view, linearLayout, false);
```

The difference is that When you inflate, it returns an object that is the same type as the top parent in the specified layout file (Which in this case is "R.layout.inflatable_player_name_view"). So I changed nameView to a TextView object and cast the returned object as a TextView. Then I specified the wanted parent layout (To get the right layoutParams) and put false so that it does not attach it automatically to that parent layout. After that I simply made the alterations to the textView that I wanted, like setting the text values and whatnot, and then manually added it to the parent linearlayout that I wanted. After doing this there was not even a need to set an onClickListener programmatically because the android:onClick method worked just fine.